# Calculation of Christoffel-Symbols for a given specific metric

Tags: differential-geometry

I am stuck with the following problem.
We are given the following metric $$ds^2 = c^2dt^2 - a^2(t)\bar{g}_{ij}dx^idx^j$$ and I want to calculate its Christoffe symbols but I keep getting the wrong answers. For example $$ \Gamma^{\mu}_{00} $$ is supposed to be 0 (greek indices run from 0 to 3, and latin indices from 1 to 3), whereas I keep getting mixed metric terms. Is there some tricks someone could share easing the pain when calculating these?

Thank you

Comment: Why don't you write down your calculations?

Comment: What does $\bar g_{ij}$ represent here?

Comment: it represents the 3-dimensional quantity

Comment: Are you sure you wrote your metric down correctly? It looks like you are trying to write an FRW metric, but in that case the scale factor, $a$, normally would be squared.

Comment: Yes, you are right, thank you. I edited it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Christoffel symbols can be obtained from the equations of motion using the rule :

$$ \frac{d^2 x^\mu}{d\lambda^2} + \Gamma^\mu_{\alpha\beta} \frac{dx^\alpha}{d\lambda} \frac{dx^\beta}{d\lambda} = 0$$

To obtain the equations of motion first write a Lagrangian based on your metric,

$$ L = -c^2 t'^2 + a^2 \bar{g}_{ij} x'^i x'^j, $$

where the $'$ denotes differentiation with respect to a parameter $\lambda$ and $\dot{}$ will represent differentiation with respect to $t$..

The Euler-Lagrange equation for the time component of the geodesic equation is then,

$$\frac{\partial L}{\partial t} = \frac{d}{d\lambda} \frac{\partial L}{\partial t'} $$

$$ 2a \dot{a} \bar{g}_{ij} x'^i x'^j = \frac{d}{d\lambda} (-2c^2t')$$

$$ 2a \dot{a} \bar{g}_{ij} x'^i x'^j = -2c^2t''$$

$$ c^2 t'' + a \dot{a} \bar{g}_{ij} x'^i x'^j = 0$$

$$  t'' + \color{blue}{\frac{1}{c^2}\left( \frac{\dot{a}}{a}\right)  a^2 \bar{g}_{ij} }x'^i x'^j = 0$$

From this we can see that,

$$ \Gamma^t_{ij} = \frac{1}{c^2}\left( \frac{\dot{a}}{a}\right)  a^2 \bar{g}_{ij} $$

Answer (score 1):

$$\Gamma^\mu_{00}= g^{\mu\tau} [0 0,\tau]$$
with
$$2[0 0,\tau]= g_{\tau 0, 0} + g_{0\tau, 0}- g_{0 0, \tau}  $$
Now $g_{00}= c^2$ is constant and $g_{\tau 0}= g_{0 \tau}$ is either constant (when $\tau = 0$) or $=0$ otherwise -- so every derivative is $=0$, too. So $\Gamma^\mu_{00}=0 $ (no mixed term). If you arrive at something else write down how you got there.

Comment: thank you, this was insightful for this particular Christoffel symbol. But what is wrong in the following calculation of $ \Gamma^i_{j0}$? 
$$\Gamma^i_{j0} = 1/2 \sum_{k=1}^3g^{ik} (g_{kj,0} + g_{k0,j}-g_{0j,k})$$ then using $ g_{0j,k} = g_{k0,j} = 0$ and that $g_{kj,0} = -\frac{\partial}{c^2\partial t}a(t)$ that $\Gamma^i_{j0} = 1/2 \sum_{k=1}^3g^{ik} g_{kj,0} =  1/(2c^2) \sum_{k=1}^3 \frac{1}{a(t)} \dot{a}(t) = 3/(2c^2) \frac{1}{a(t)} \dot{a}(t) $?

Comment: i can not edit my comment, but I corrected the metric in my first comment, a should be squared. I am sorry